# Cómo obtener la URL completa en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

Necesito obtener la URL **completa** dentro de un componente de mi aplicación de Angular.

Por ejemplo, en un entorno de desarrollo mi aplicación corre en `localhost:4200`. Supongamos que he navegado a `/home`. Me gustaría obtener la URL completa, `http://localhost:4200/home`, desde el componente.

He intentado inyectar `Router`y `Location`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.location);
    console.log(this.router);
  }
}
```

Sin embargo con ellos solo puedo obtener rutas relativas (por ejempo, `/home`).

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Veo que pones javascript, te sirve un script cortito de JS para obtenerla? si es así con `window.location.href` sacas la url entera.

Comment: @Emerita en este caso está programando con Angular, así que será mejor que mantenga como tal. Es mala práctica hacer algo fuera del entorno.

Comment: Entonces elimina la etiqueta javascript de la pregunta, porque seguro que no soy el único que te pregunta lo mismo jejejejeje.

Comment: No entiendo porqué debería eliminarla... Angular es un framework Javascript, igual que muchos otros... A mi me sirvió para poder recibir la notificación.

Comment: @dteterevkov Si sabes que tu aplicación siempre se va a ejecutar en un navegador normal, no hay nada malo en usar el objeto `document`, a veces con Angular pecamos de *sobreingeniería*

Comment: El código de la pregunta es claramente Typescript, ¿por qué eliminar la etiqueta?

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios, la verdad es que no pensé en usar puro Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo relacionado con las rutas se encuentra en el objeto `location`, pero en este caso, como digo en los comentarios, debes acceder a ella usando las herramientas que te proporciona Typescript y Angular.

Así que importas `DOCUMENT`, lo declaras, y ya puedes acceder a ello.

Para ver más acerca el objeto `location`te recomiendo el siguiente [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any) {
    console.log(document.location.href);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, muy interesante, no sabía que se podía importar document