# Capturar datos de URL con Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Un servicio de pagos me redirecciona a mi pagina con algunos datos en la url ej:

```
https://mipaginaweb/respuestaPago?status=approved&name=Pepito_Peres&address=Avenida_8-64&telephone=6658822
```

Pero como hago para capturar los datos de esa url y pintarlos en una tabla que ya tengo contruidad en esa ruta https://mipaginaweb/respuestaPago

Comment: Fijate en este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249950/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-url-completa-en-angular) Como obtiene la ruta document.location.href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba inyectando ActivatedRoute y suscribirte a query params

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

@Component({...})

export class MiComponente implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        const status= params['status'];
        const name= params['name'];
        const address= params['address'];
        const telephone= params['telephone'];
      
       console.log(`status:${status} name:${name} address:${address} telephone${telephone}`)
      });
  }

}
```